# Do the first k numbers of geometric progression cover all possible numbers?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Original problem: we are looking for up to first ten digits of decimal representation of powers of 2

$$\require{cancel}2^0 = 1 \to \{1\}\\
2^1 = 2 \to \{2\}\\
...\\
2^{10}=1024\to\{1,10,102,1024\}\\
...\\
2^{578}=9893216058\cancel{92\dots}\to\{9,98,989,\dots,9893216058\}\\
...$$

will we see all numbers from $[1,10^{10}-1]$ in resulting sets after some time?

For simplicity we can look for exactly first ten digits ($2^{10}\to\{1024\}, 2^{578}\to\{9893216058\}$) and expect all numbers in $[10^9,10^{10}-1]$.

I believe that powers of 2 does not have special meaning here and answer will fit some other geometric progressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, every number will appear. Note that any number resulting from this procedure can be written as, for some positive $a$ and $b$,
$$\left\lfloor\frac{2^a}{10^b}\right\rfloor.$$
And, any number of the above form could certainly be generated by the above procedure. The thing to note here is that the set of numbers of the form $\frac{2^a}{10^b}$ is dense in the non-negative reals - to see this quickly, note the ratio of $\log(2)$ and $\log(10)$ is irrational, since 10 and 2 share no common integer powers. Thus, the set $a\log(2)-b\log(10)=\log(\frac{2^a}{10^b})$ is dense in the reals. Quite clearly, if a set S is dense in the non-negative reals, then the set of $\lfloor s \rfloor$ for $s\in S$ includes every natural number.

This generalizes to say that, in base $b$, for any string of digits and any number $k$ such that $\log_b(k)$ is irrational, some integer power of $k$ will include the given string of digits at its start.